# Easier URL to an image

Tags: php

Currently in development for a client's website and when I type the image source I do not want to type out something similar to this as it can get very messy:

```
<img src="../CLIENT/wp-content/themes/aroma/images/logo.png"/>
```

Is there a template tag or something that'll enable me to just jump into my theme's folder and link from there? The code could look like something similar to this:

```
<img src="<?php image_source('images/logo.png')?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png">
```

Comment: For even faster access I usually create a constant in my function.php for easier access in my theme. :) `<?php define('theme_base', get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>`

Comment: Nice, didn't know that yet. How do you echo the directory with this technique?

Comment: After defining it in your functions.php, you can access it in any theme file by echoing it as a constant. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php So, <?php echo constant_name; ?> would echo the value of your constant; here get_template_directory_uri()

Comment: Thanks, never used that before. This is good for the performance as the server has to retrieve the directory only once, isn't it? And does it makes sense to do this with all other possible directories, too?

Comment: I use constants for things I use EVERY single time. Like timthumb for example!

Comment: For something like images get_stylesheet_directory() might be a better option depending on the situation... Also, if you're really lazy like me and you use the image folder all the time you could turn that into a constant as well. `define('THEMENAME_IMAGES', trailingslashit(trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory_uri()) . 'images'));` Then you just need `<img src="<?php echo THEMENAME_IMAGES ?>logo.png">` and then you only have to worry about the file.